# Уровень вложенности для пункта меню

Tags: mysql, sql

[image: введите сюда описание изображения]

Табличка menu простая name, url, parent (название, куда переходить и родительский пункт меню)...

Какой запрос нужно написать, чтобы вывести ещё level - уровень вложенности для пункта меню?

Comment: А можете предоставить структуру таблицы картинкой?

Comment: Обновил вопрос...

Answer (score 1):

Если максимальный уровень заранее известен и не очень большой, то можно джойнами перебрать все уровни.

```
select m1.*,
case
  when m1.parent is null then 1
  when m2.parent is null then 2
  when m3.parent is null then 3
  when m4.parent is null then 4
  else null 
end as level
from menu m1
left join menu m2 on m2.id = m1.parent
left join menu m3 on m3.id = m2.parent
left join menu m4 on m3.id = m3.parent
```

Если же максимальный уровень не известен, то только с использованием хранимой процедуры (пример для PostgreSQL):

```
create function get_level(integer) returns integer as $$
declare
  a_parent alias for $1;
  level integer;
  result integer;
begin
  level = 1;
  result = a_parent;
  while result is not null
  loop
     select parent from menu where id = result into result;
     level = level + 1;
  end loop;
  return level;
end;
$$ language plpgsql;
```

ну и вывод результата:

```
select *, get_level(parent) from menu
```

Answer (score 0):

Ну примерно запрос должен быть построен так: По началу Вы делаете запрос на те строки, у которых `parent = NULL`.

```
$mysqli = new mysqli('127.0.0.1', 'root', '1111', 'mysite');
$level = 0;
$menu = $mysqli->query("SELECT * FROM menu WHERE `parent` = NULL ")
    $menu = $menu->fetch_all();

    foreach ($menu as $main_item) {
        echo "<ul>";
        $item = $mysqli->query("SELECT * FROM menu WHERE `parent` = '{$main_item[0]}'");
        $is_tree = $item->num_rows;
        if ($is_tree > 0) {
            echo '<li class="submenu">';
            $items = $item->fetch_all();
            $level++;
            $upd = $mysqli->query("update menu set `level`='{$level}' where `id`='{$main_item[0]}' LIMIT 1");
            echo "<ul>";
            foreach ($items as $child_item) {
                echo "<li onclick=window.open('{$child_item[2]}')>{$child_item[1]}</li>";
            }
            echo "</ul>";
            echo '</li>';
        } else {
            echo "<li onclick=window.open('{$main_item[2]}')>{$main_item[1]}</li>";
        }
        echo "</ul>";
    }
```

Я думаю, что так должно работать.
Просьба не пинать минусами